# Powershell Getting InvokeMethodOnNull Message

Tags: powershell

```ps
[xml] $opex = Get-Content(Get-ChildItem $_ *.opex).FullName } 

If((-not $opex.OPEXMetadata.DescriptiveMetadata.METATRANSCRIPT.HasAttribute('ArchiveHandle'))-or (-not $opex.OPEXMetadata.DescriptiveMetadata.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Resources.MediaFile.ResourceLink.HasAttribute('ArchiveHandle')) -or (-not $opex.OPEXMetadata.DescriptiveMetadata.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Resources.WrittenResource.ResourceLink.HasAttribute('ArchiveHandle'))){
```

Hi, I'm getting the follow message with my if statement gets a null value. Is there any way to workaround this issue?

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
> C:\Users\User\Documents\ScripsPS1\Missing_AH.ps1:26 char:8
>
> - If((-not $opex.OPEXMetadata.DescriptiveMetadata.METATRANSCRIPT.Ha ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: With ISE you can put a breakpoint and find out what object is getting null value in this expression.

Comment: Hi @derloopkat, thanks for your reply. I know what are the objects that are getting null values, the idea is ignore them or avoid the InvokeMethodOnNull message

Comment: If you know what's null, the solution is obvious. Just check for nulls on these objects **before** calling a method. Do you know how to check for null value in your code?